# Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not focusable

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am currently working with C# using selenium webdriver. `sendkeys` was working however now it is ultimately not working.

I have tried the following

- Click on search box before trying to send keys (this works, it clicks on the element)
- tried focusing on the iframe since I deal with iframes, however same thing and it clicks on the element however doesn't enter the keys.
- I've also tried adding a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 *1000);` (also doesn't work)

I have tried all the different xpath however I am using the same xpath as when clicking on the element so realistically this should be working.

As I am passing through data from memory that didn't work, `sendKeys(Program, data)`, I have also tried passing through hard coded data such as a number (`sendkey("111");`). None of the above work.

I work with only C# on this so all suggestions to resolve this would be very helpful  :)

Comment: If possible then try to provide your C# code and your HTML code. It can help to make a test on our side to see the results. You are trying to enter text in a textbox in an iframe, am I correct?